Event listeners are removed from TextBox when it loses focus
I'm working with event listeners on an asp.net TextBox and they do work fine until it loses focus. Once it does that it seems that event listeners are removed and they don't fire at all as noted by the absence of logging in the console. My code should mask input text after 3rd character and ensure the cursor is positioned always at the end of text. Is there any way to reattach the listeners?
Here I show a vanilla example having two input html boxes. In my original scenario those are asp.net controls and the javascript to acquire their id is using in the first case: '<%= TxtAccountName.ClientID%>' ... since this live snippet works as intended I suspect the issue is related to the asp.net scenario. Does anyone have any suggestion?


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  let node = document.getElementById('TxtAccountName');
  let hidden = document.getElementById('HFAccName');

  node.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

    console.log("Fired the keydown event")
    //compares the cursorPosition to the length of text

    if (node.selectionStart !== node.value.length) {
      e.preventDefault();
      positionAtEndOfText();
    }
  });

  node.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {  
    console.log("Fired keyup event")

    let text = node.value;
    if (text.length > 3) {
      node.value = text.substring(0, 3) + '*'.repeat(text.length - 3);
    }
  });

  node.addEventListener('input', function() {
    console.log("Fired input event")

    if (node.selectionStart !== node.value.length) {
      e.preventDefault();
      positionAtEndOfText();
    }
  });
});



function positionAtEndOfText() {

  let text = node.value;

  node.focus();



  if (node.setSelectionRange) {

    node.setSelectionRange(text.length, text.length);

  } else if (node.createTextRange) {

    let range = node.createTextRange();

    range.collapse(true)

    range.moveEnd('character', value.length)

    range.moveStart('character', value.length)

    range.select()

  }

}
<input id="TxtAccountName">
<input id="HFAccName">



I tried having a 'focus' event but apparently it didn't work.

Your code does not behave as you describe - i.e. it works like you want it to work

they do work fine until it loses focus ... can you please be more clear? since the event you are listening to is keydown of course the element must have focus for the event to trigger. What did you expect instead? By the way you can just  make it a vanilla demo without involving asp.net in the game for the sake of addressing your specific problem

@DiegoD Yes I do understand that, the thing is the events don't fire once you regain focus. So for example when having focus for the first time code works. But once you position your mouse outside of the texbox, then click again in it and write text, none of those events logs text in the console or perform any action

I just turned your exact code as a live snippet (I only added the 2 input elements and used their id straight instead of using the asp.net strategy). Are you observing the same behaviour as yours?

as a further note I would change the way you refer to the element inside the event listeners. Instead of using node that is defined above in the scope, you should use e.target

In the code snippet, it's working right as it is supposed to work. Could it be something with partial postbacks in my server-side messing up javascript code? I will fix the node-target part in my code, thank you!

since I don't have further insights related to asp.net behaviours, I added a note in the edited question showing the original intentions.. maybe someone will better address the issue

Could it be something with partial postbacks in my server-side messing up javascript code? Yes! If you use an UpdatePanel the jquery bindings will be lost and you will have to rebind them.

Using Update panel is HUGE information here. Update panel will not change anything when you click outside of the text box, and then click back to text box. However, a HUGE MASSIVE LARGE Mount Everest issue will exist if you saying that after a update panel posts-back, and the events stop working? Then yes, that detail is HUGE and massive! Best guess is text box events ONLY fail after a update panel post back.  So it NOT ONLY that you changing focus, but you are in fact posting  back part of the update via Update Panel, and THEN the events don't work. Is this your case?

So, it looks like the issue is NOT just moving focus, and the client events fail, but that of WHEN a partial page post back "inside" of an update panel occurs, then the events start failing.
This makes sense, since the WHOLE idea of update panel is to post back only PART of the page. Do keep in mind that when using a UP that a standard page life cycle does occur in that the page load event will fire EVERY time, and then say the button event inside of that UP will then run. In other words, a similar page life cycle round trip occurs, and standard code behind events do run and trigger.
This of course means that your page load event code (that typical sets up controls, loads combo boxes etc.) will run each time. Hence, for the last 200 ASPX pages I have built, then you need to follow this design pattern:
Place an if !IsPostBack code stub in the on-load event, so it ONLY runs one time, and only runs on the real first page load.
Hence this:
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        LoadTable()
        ' Setup of controls and data goes here 
        ' This code runs ONLY one time on first real page load

    End If

End Sub

So, keep the above in mind. The above also applies when using an update panel.
Now, the second issue is of course when using an update panel, then jQuery.ui, selectors and code that should run AFTER the page loads? Well, with an update panel, then those standard JavaScript events (such as page on-ready) etc. will NOT run when using an UP. However, that markup inside of the UP will come back to the client side all fresh and new. This means that you need to re-run any JavaScript event hook ups.
As a FYI, I tend to NOT write code to hook up events, since then when looking at markup and controls, you now have two places to look at! The control's markup, and then some place else that you have some JavaScript.
So, while I am about to show how you can have such JavaScript code run again after a partial page post back (a UP), you should probably adopt a coding standard in which you define, and setup and declare the events for a given control in the markup, and not write MORE code to wire up an event when you could have in the first place written the markup events anyway.
In other words, writing code to hook up events in near all cases is not required, and it makes your markup far more readable if you simply write out the events for the given control in the first place.
Also, it is not at all clear why you using HTML controls as opposed to asp.net ones? ASP.net controls are for the most part much the same as the HTML controls, but the HUGE difference is that asp.net controls and their value(s) can be freely used in your code behind, where as your input controls are difficult to deal with.
And before we go down this "expensive" road to write a whole bunch of JavaScript code?
I would consider using a standard text box, set textmode = "password", and then below the text box, use a label, and display the first 3 characters.
hence this markup:
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtAccountName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
            TextMode="Password"
            onkeyup="mykeyup()">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lablefirst3" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="cmdDone" runat="server" Text="Submit"
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdDone_Click" />
        <script>

            function mykeyup() {
                // transfer first 3 chars to Label below password text box
                lablefirst3.innerText = TxtAccountName.value.substring(0, 3)
            }

        </script>

And code behind can thus just reference the text box.
Protected Sub cmdDone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim sPasword As String = TxtAccountName.Text

    ' ** optional restore pw after post back
    ' For reasons of security, WHEN using textmode="password", then on
    ' ANY post back, the text box is automatically cleared. Hence code
    ' Below will restore the value if you wishing to by-pass this 
    ' Security measure.

    TxtAccountName.Attributes.Add("value", TxtAccountName.Text)

    ' Do whatever here

End Sub

Hence, result is this:

Hence, we really don't need or want a whole bunch of expensive JavaScript code for such a simple task.
And if you really do want the first 3 chars, and then "*"?
Then I suppose you could use your existing code, but I would wire up the events in the markup, and avoid using the page load/ready event and then have to run some JavaScript code to ensure that some controls will run their JavaScript code (hence, as suggested, don't use JavaScript code to wire up controls to run more JavaScript, but simply specify the function to run in the controls markup, and all your troubles will be eliminated).
However, if you want your existing code that "attaches" and runs and wires up the events?
Then you can use this event for the update panel:
Place this code right after the update panel end tags.
Hence:
<script>
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(myrunone);
    function myrunone() {
        let node = document.getElementById('TxtAccountName');
        let hidden = document.getElementById('HFAccName');

        node.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
            console.log("Fired the keydown event")
            //compares the cursorPosition to the length of text

           if (node.selectionStart !== node.value.length) {
               e.preventDefault();
               positionAtEndOfText();
           }
        });

        node.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {  
            console.log("Fired keyup event")

            let text = node.value;
            if (text.length > 3) {
                node.value = text.substring(0, 3) + '*'.repeat(text.length - 3);
            }
        });

        node.addEventListener('input', function() {
            console.log("Fired input event")

            if (node.selectionStart !== node.value.length) {
                e.preventDefault();
                positionAtEndOfText();
            }
        });
     });



     function positionAtEndOfText() {
         let text = node.value;

         node.focus();

         if (node.setSelectionRange) {
             node.setSelectionRange(text.length, text.length);

         } else if (node.createTextRange) {

             let range = node.createTextRange();

             range.collapse(true)

             range.moveEnd('character', value.length)

             range.moveStart('character', value.length)

             range.select()

         }

     }
 </script>

So, you need your existing code, which runs (and wires up the events) as you have. And THEN you need the code to run again after a update panel post-back occurs, and thus you need to repeat the code. Of course, you could as noted simply wire up the events by using onkeyup, and onkeydown, and specify the routine(s) to run, and thus no need to "run the wire up" code when the page is finished loading.
And I would of course over time re-write your code to have the control(s) passed, so you have some JavaScript code that eliminates the hard coding of the controls so such code can with ease be re-used.

Thank you for the thorough and complete answer, that helped me solve the problem!
